# How to UPDATE sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems with the UPDATE statements

Here's the tables I'm suppose to update

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_mys (
 CustID     VARCHAR(5)      NOT NULL,
 CustFName  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 CustLName  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 CustPhone  CHAR(10),
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (CustID)
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Product_mys (
 ProductID  NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 ProductName    VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
 CatID      Number(3)       NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (ProductID)
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Commission_mys (
 CommClass  CHAR(1)         NOT NULL,
 CommRate   Number(2,2)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (CommClass) 
 ) ;
```

Here's What I have so far (I did the customer table but have no idea how to do the product or commission tables)

```
--Update Customer A120's last name
UPDATE Customer_mys
   SET CustLName = 'Thompson'
 WHERE CustID = 'A120' ;

--Update Customer J090's phone number
UPDATE Customer_mys
   SET CustPhone = '2146881234'
 WHERE CustID = 'J090' ;
```

This is what I'm suppose to use to UPDATE the tables with

Customer table

Change the last name of Customer A120 to “Thompson”
Change the phone number of Customer J090 to “2146881234”

Product table

Change the price of Product 121 to $7.50 for Order 100 in Order Detail, and change its ProductName to “BD Claw Hammer” in the Product table.

Add 5 new products with the following attributes:

```
ProductID   ProductName         CatID
122     BD Rubber Mallet            1
125     Stanley Chisel              1
126     BD Chisel                   1
381     BD Measuring Tape           3
382     Stanley Measuring Tape      3
```

Commission table

Add a new commission class with the following attributes:

```
    CommClass   CommRate
            D              .03
```

Comment: If you can update a customer name you should be able to update a product name. You can update a product price the same way but you need two conditions with an `AND` (you haven't posted the order detail table schema). The rest will require `INSERT` queries. Good luck.

Comment: what problems are you having updating ?

Comment: Show what you have done so far, and the `error` you are facing, looks pretty simple because you have `no relationship` between them